# validate email and phone number within same field in angular 5

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I am using angular 6 and I have sign-in form same as Gmail. Like user can enter email or phone number. So I want to validate both on the client side. I will do in server-side in laravel php. Please suggest me with the best way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Asking Question without the code snippet in question is not a good practice. You need to include the code that does not work as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) no screen shots. We are here to help but if you think someone will do your job then forget it. Please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then Edit your question and improve it

Comment: Please add some code. So that we can know what you have done so far.

Comment: You can start by decifering whether it's an E-mail, or a phone number that has been entered. You can do that by using regular expressions. You basically check if the input matches the correct syntax of an E-mail. If not, you then check if it matches the correct syntax of a phone number, i.e. contains the correct amount of numbers and allowed characters (if any, maybe a "+" sign?). Then depending on error inputs you can prompt a message to the user of invalid input bla bla. That's the pointer I'll give you. Come back with attempts if you're stuck anywhere.

Comment: given information is not enough, Give some code what you have tried and clear few of questions given  bellow

Comment: Are you using form builder for UI validation?

Comment: Are you using reactive forms?

Comment: Only TS level validation enough ?

Comment: Yes, I am using reactive forms.

Answer (score 2):

In Angular 4+,
For Client side validation use Reactive forms.

**Use Form in your html**

```
<form [formGroup]="login_form" (submit)="submitForm()">
  <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Enter email" formControlName="email" />
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="login_form.controls['email'].hasError('required') && (login_form.controls['email'].dirty || login_form.controls['email'].touched)">Email address is required</span>
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="login_form.controls['email'].hasError('email') && (login_form.controls['email'].dirty || login_form.controls['email'].touched)">Please enter valid email address</span>
    
  
  <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" formControlName="password" />
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="login_form.controls['password'].hasError('required') && (login_form.controls['password'].dirty || login_form.controls['password'].touched)">Password is required</span>
  
  
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary mt-lg" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

**Use Below code in your Component**

```
// First install this package using below cli command
// npm install ng2-validation --save

import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomValidators } from 'ng2-validation';

export class YourComponent {

  public login_form: FormGroup;
  
  public submitForm(){        
    if (this.login_form.valid) {
      // You will get form value if your form is valid
      var formValues = this.login_form.value;    
      ....
    } else {
      // For Angular 4,5.
      for (let v in this.login_form.controls) {
         this.login_form.controls[v].markAsTouched();
      }

      // For Angular 6+ versions.
      this.login_form.markAllAsTouched();
    }
  }

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.login_form = fb.group({
      'email': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, CustomValidators.email])],
      'password': [null, Validators.required],
    });
  }
```

StackBlitz for Testing : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/email-phone-validation-reactive)

Comment: No, This is validating the only email. But I need to validate mobile number on the same field.

Comment: Then you can use your custom validation using regex, try this one : "/^([_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,5}))|(\d+$)$/" or if its not work try this one : "/^(?:\d{10}|\w+@\w+\.\w{2,3})$/", Please don't use "" (Quotation marks)

Comment: When i test online "/^(?:\d{10}|\w+@\w+\.\w{2,3})$/", this is working good but when i used in my project angular 6 then it is not working good.

Comment: @NiteshKaushik, i had created one stackblitz demo with angular 6 with this validation :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d36f5p